# Customizing query from Azure Devops Dashboard Widget

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-dashboard

Is there a way to make a query criteria as customizable from the dashboard widget? Say for example, if iteration path is one of my query clause, I want to change the value in run time from the widget to generate the results. Right now am using the query results widget.

Is there any widget in marketplace which provides this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any widget in marketplace which provides this feature?

I fully understand your needs, but I am afraid there is no such widget in marketplace which provides this feature at this time. Currently, the [query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/widget-catalog?view=azure-devops#query-results) widget is the closest extension to the demand.

If we want to add a custom query criteria on the dashboard widget, we have two directions to achieve it. One is adding query criteria to perform a second query on the results of Shared Queries, another is reflecting the query criteria set on the widget to the Shared Queries criteria and modify the original criteria. Obviously neither of these two methods are easy to implement, and there is still a long way to go.

In my opinion your request is reasonable, you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]